# Wxpython, how to create wx.KeyEvent with given key code?

Tags: python, events, key, wxpython

I'm trying to create a **wx.KeyEvent** object, I need it to emulate key press in **wx.TextCtrl**. I don't want to propagate the event (if possible), just create an object. Is there a way to do this?

I've looked at **wx.KeyEvent** page on the wxpython.org, yet I didn't find any useful information. My only hint is that maybe I could create a **wx.Event** object and give it the parameters I want?

**EDIT**: I've tried instantiating an Event object with `eventType=wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN`, but I get the exception saying that it cannot be subclassed/instantiated. No wonder, cause how would I even pass parameters into it.

Comment: Creating low level events is not a good idea. Describe what you are trying to do, and we may find a better way. You can SetInsertPoint, select, edit, and what not.

Comment: I am trying to implement auto completion in `wx.RichTextCtrl`, If I remember it correctly then `SetInsertionPoint` couldn't help me, as I am also styling the text depending on the content. for example numbers are of different color than keywords or parantheses. I found that only `EmulateKeyPress` worked for me. Other forms would only work partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate keys, text and mouse actions with `wx.UIActionSimulator` https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.UIActionSimulator.html

i.e.

```
keyinput = wx.UIActionSimulator()
keyinput.Char(ord("z"))
keyinput.Char(ord("\t"))
```

would simulate a "z" followed by a tab

Actions available are:

```
> Char  Press and release a key.
> KeyDown   Press a key.
> KeyUp Release a key.
> MouseClick    Click a mouse button.
> MouseDblClick Double-click a mouse button.
> MouseDown Press a mouse button.
> MouseDragDrop Perform a drag and drop operation.
> MouseMove Move the mouse to the specified coordinates.
> MouseUp   Release a mouse button.
> Text  Emulate typing in the keys representing the given string.
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony and what if I need to do the reverse thing - simulate an EVT_BUTTON event when a hotkey press is detected?

Comment: @ivan866 Best create a question with your scenario described in detail.

Comment: Note that `wxUIActionSimulator` requires wxWidgets to have been built with XTest support, which is currently not the case on Debian (see: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1037164).